# Shopware 6: How to test against newly released Shopware versions without using dockware?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, shopware, shopware6

I am currently using dockware in my shell scripts to get Shopware docker images for testing. However, dockware takes some time to upload the latest Shopware versions after they are released, like `6.5.7.0`.

I would like to be able to test against newly released Shopware versions as soon as possible. How can I pull the latest Shopware docker images without relying on dockware?

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 dockware/dev:6.5.7.0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have created a PR at the Dockware repository https://github.com/dockware/dockware/pull/199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I created a [PR](https://github.com/dockware/dockware/pull/199) at the [Dockware](https://github.com/dockware/dockware) repository, which has been merged. The [tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockware/dev/tags) for the new version should appear soon.

For future updates:

Dockware provides a tutorial to create it with a new Shopware Version:

https://github.com/dockware/dockware#creating-a-new-shopware-version

> Creating a new Shopware Version.
> At the moment, the step to add a new Shopware version is to manually create a few files, but it's still very easy.
> Add 2 new folders to variants/play and variants/dev (just copy the previous release). Then open the variables.json in each folder and adjust the Shopware Version, as well as the Download URL.
> Afterwards, add the new entries in the manifest.json. Please don't forget to move the alias "latest" to the correct version.
> Now open the file build/WorkflowBuilder/Constant.php and adjust the correct latest Shopware version. This is for Cypress double verifications.
> Then open the build folder in your CLI and run "make generate-tests" to also create new SVRUnit tests.
> Also adjust the Github workflows to build all required images.
> That's it! You can now commit your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ddev as an alternative for this task. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ for an introduction to ddev.

See https://gist.github.com/vanWittlaer/def64280969ff3e8d2934ac03b206828 for an installation script that would bring up the latest stable Shopware 6 version.